# Visual Studio 2017. Как удалить?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017.

Установил.
Потом пробовал удалить, но до конца удалить не получилось, из-за отключения электричества в доме.

В результате:
 - Visual Studio запускается и работает;
 - в "Панель управления\Программы\Программы и компоненты" Visual Studio 2017 отсутствует, т.е. удалить её нельзя;
 - в меню "пуск" см. скрин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения];

**Вопрос**
Как удалить Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Попробуйте взять инсталлятор, и в нем выбрать опцию удаления.

Answer (score 4):

А [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio) были?

Предлагают найти файл **InstallCleanup.exe** (по умолчанию C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe) и запустить его с правами администратора: либо с ключом "-i" (если в будущем планируется повторная установка этой версии Visual Studio), либо с ключом "-f" (если требуется полное удаление продукта насовсем). Последний вариант может затронуть компоненты, используемые другими инсталляцими Visual Studio.

Если такого файла нет - нужно запустить заново установку Visual Studio, дождаться, пока она дойдёт до выбора задачи, и закрыть окно установки. После этого файл **InstallCleanup.exe** должен появиться в указанной папке.

Answer (score 1):

Как раз для вашего случая у MS есть [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller)